# What is the meaning of following code of react native and redux

Tags: react-native, redux, middleware, redux-thunk, reducers

I am referring the code of an existing project and I am stuck at the point where I am not getting the purpose of the code.

I have started using redux currently and directly found code like below which contains middleware.

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
```

I am not getting what is this code is doing. Please help me to understand what these three lines of code doing.

Answer (score 2):

`const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);`

This line creates a function (`createStoreWithMiddleware`) which will take a list of arguments and create a store object which applies the [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware. Thunk allows you to handle side effect logic more easily.

`const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);`

This line is combining all of your separate reducers into one complete reducer. This means that whenever an action is dispatched, it is sent to all of the reducers in your project.

`const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);`

This line is creating your store using your reducer from the previous line, so that the `thunk` middleware is applied.

Answer (score 1):

The **applyMiddleware** function is just a way to extend redux with custom functionalities. In your case you are using **thunk** which is a way to invert control to your actions by dispatching functions. You can also combine more functionalities, **logger** is an useful one.

The second line **combineReducers** you are just combining all your reducers defined in your implementation. Since you can have multiple of them, it lets you store the states in the same store.

The third line you are just creating the store with the reducers combined and the custom functionalities that you defined previously.

You can read more about the applyMiddleware here:
https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware